# Use video for camera emulator in Android Studio for debugging camera / image recognition based App

Tags: applications, usb-debugging, avd-manager

I need to debug some image recognition app and therefore need a specific camera input to see if the app is working.

Is there a way to use a custom recorded video, for example using the `Android Virtual Device` manager and it's emulated camera?

Comment: AFAIK only "real" webcam streams can be forwarded to the emulator. However there are applications that simulate a webcam (e.g. to Windows) based on a video.